# kendo Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'min')

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a problem on my kendo, when i tried to reload the page, it works properly but when I tried to reload multiple times i got an 2 error, `please see the error below` is this the limitation of kendo or there is something wrong with my code that causes the error?

i think the problem here is there is no validation that if `min` property is exist inn the page, i dont know how to put the validation.

```
var curdate = new Date();
$calendarPopup.find('[kendo="date-picker"]').kendoDatePicker({
    value: curdate,
    min: curdate,
    change: function (e) {
         if (this.value() > curdate) {
             $('[name="entry-start-time"]').data('kendoTimePicker').min('12:00 AM');
             $('[name="entry-start-time"]').data('kendoTimePicker').value(curdate);
         } else {
             $('[name="entry-start-time"]').data('kendoTimePicker').min(curdate);
             $('[name="entry-start-time"]').data('kendoTimePicker').value(curdate);
         }
     },
   });

   var date = $(`input[name='entry-start-date']`).data('kendoDatePicker');
       date.min(curdate); // this is where the error pointing out

   // DATETIME PICKER
   $calendarPopup.find('[name="entry-start-time"]').kendoTimePicker({
        value: new Date(),
             dateInput: false,
   });
   // DROPDOWN LIST
   $calendarPopup.find('[kendo="drop-down-list"]').kendoDropDownList();                
  }
```

I've got two error I saw on my console

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you sure `('[name="entry-start-time"]')` is kendoTimePicker ?

Comment: @dangerousmanleesanghyeon yes

Comment: @LunaWest You should provide also your HTML markup and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)